# iOS application does not open rss feed properly

Tags: ios, xml-parsing, rss

Sorry for stupid question that I will ask. So, I have a problem with iOS app development. This app is basically simple RSS reader that work as a parser. When I put RSS link in usually works correctly, but now, when I put link of one university, Instead of opening the file after clicking to the title (any news),

[image: this is list of news]

doesn`t open page that I select, instead of it, it opens webpage with news:

[image: opens list of news on website]

if u know something about my question, please advise me something. Thanks you

Comment: Show some confidence!

Comment: This question is lacking so much information, I don't think anyone can help with what's provided. Try adding more information about your process.

Answer (score 0):

Please Use Flatten HTML methods as it seems there are lot of characters which need to replace to show content as it should be.